# Get inexistent system user info without the output

Tags: ruby, linux, macos

This is my code for getting all system users:

```
 def get_all_system_users
  user_paths = Dir["#{ENV['HOME']}/../*"]
  users = user_paths.map { |path| path.split("..")[-1].gsub(/\W/, '') }
  users.select { |user| %x{id #{user}}.include?("uid") }
end
```

The problem is the **id #{user}** command which returns an output for inexistent users that bubbles all the way, exactly like a puts or pp.

How can I mute it but still evaluate the output of the command?

Comment: Isn't it easier to scan /etc/passwd file? (if OSX has this file)

Comment: Yes, it would, but OS X doesn't store system users in /etc/passwd. First place I looked ; ). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer a more direct way: (EDIT: Updated to work with OSX, I think)

```
def get_all_system_users
  `dscacheutil -q user|grep name:|cut -d: -f2`.split
end
```

Or, to handle multiple OSes:

```
require 'rbconfig'

def get_all_system_users
  case RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
    when /mac|darwin/i
      `dscacheutil -q user|grep name:|cut -d: -f2`.split
    when /linux/i
      `cat /etc/passwd|grep "/home"|cut -d: -f1`.split
    else
      raise "InferiorOS Error" #or whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: Very nice and elegant, like your use of cut, should get it under my belt.I need this to work on OS X as well, because I wouldn't have even bothered of working out the users home dir path starting from ENV['HOME'].

Comment: @Gerhard I don't have access to an OS X box right now, but it would seem that `dscacheutil -q user |grep name:|cut -d: -f2` would be an easy and correct way to get the list of users.

Comment: This is just brilliant! Low level, cross platform - me likey!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to redirect the stderr to stdout (or dev/null), but it depends on your shell:

```
%x{id #{user} 2>&1}
```

..and you will need to detect when the utility returned a failure code:

```
if $?.success?
```

Comment: Yes, you've nailed it! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just parse the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
Hash[File.readlines('/etc/passwd').map { |line|
       line.split ':'
     }.select { |field|
       field[5].index('/home/') == 0 && File.directory?(field[5])
     }.map { |field|
       [field[0], field[2].to_i]
     }]
```

This will return a hash with *username* as key and *uid* as value for
all users with an existing home directory under `/home/`.

Comment: This looks awesome and, if I didn't want OS X support, this would be simply brilliant!